# mount jailed zfs partition on boot

Tags: freebsd, jail

Whenever I reboot my FreeBSD system, I have to log on to one of my jails to manually mount a filesystem with zfs mount. The partition has the jailed zfs property. The jail is managed with ezjail but jails themself are all on a ufs partition. The dataset is listed in the ezjail config file for the jail.

Comment: Try asking at http://unix.stackexchange.com/. They may be able to provide a suitable answer. This site is for programming question.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is, that the dataset only is attached to the jail, after the rc script is done. So the zfs rc script inside the jail doesn't find the dataset and thus can not mount it.

Once the rc.d/jail script has an understanding of dataset, the dataset can be attached, after the jail is created but before it is executed.